# maven 2 plugins (less and handlebars)

Tags: maven-2, less, handlebars.js

I would like to add my handlebars and less pre-compiling into a Maven build. All the plugins i can find are for Maven 3, however I am stuck using Maven 2.0.11.

I have found handlebars-maven-plugin and lesscss-maven-plugin but both choke the build.

I am currently doing the precompiling in gulp tasks, but we cannot put node.js on the server to allow me to run these either!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That you don't find plugins for Maven 2.0.11 i can understand, cause [Maven 2.2.1 is already EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) and Maven 2.0 long time ago...so upgrade to Maven 3.

Comment: khmarbaise i completely agree with you that we should upgrade but unfortunately my hands are tied and i have no choice but to use these versions

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the same boat as me, stuck with out-dated versions, I have managed to find a solution.

For the handlebars i found this solution, [Precompiling handlerbars tempates with Rhino.js](http://blog.selvakn.in/2012/05/precompiling-handlerbars-tempates-with.html). I had to tweak the rhino-handlebars-compiler.js to take into account the extension change for handlebars, but that was it.

With regards to LESS, i discovered that version 1.3.0 of lesscss-maven-plugin is compatible with maven2 and jdk 1.5

Comment: `lesscss-maven-plugin` is not supported any more and is compatible with `LESS 1.3.0`. It has also a lot of bugs: https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin/issues. Did you try my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To compile Less files, you can use [biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin](http://lesscss-maven-plugin.projects.gabrys.biz/), which is compatible with:

- Less 1.7.5
- Maven 2.0.11
- JDK 1.5